# How to cure eczema on my foot?

Tags: dermatology

I am suffering from dry eczema on my foot over the past 6 years. I used moisturizing creams and pills as prescribed by skin specialists. As a result, I got a cure which was just temporary. It came over again.

I also made a paste of neem tree leaves and applied it on the affected skin. But still pus discharge has not stopped. Normally I used to wear flip-flops or leather sandals.

Now the real problem is, I have to wear formal shoes with socks to my workplace. How can I get a cure to this, or atleast, How can I prevent the pus from spreading over? Please help

Comment: Hello, Vijayaram, and welcome to Health.SE. This question is requesting advice that is specific to your situation, and it’s not safe for us to provide that here. If you would like to [edit] to make it about general health, please flag it so that we can see about re-opening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly is it definitely eczema and is it only eczema?**

The discharge of pus suggests a bacterial infection (probably staphylococcal). Now this could be superimposed on eczema (which causes the skin barrier to break down causing an infection) or simply just a skin infection/abscess. Either way, if it really is an infection this usually requires antibiotics. Thus you should see a doctor.

**If it is eczema, once the infection is treated:**

- Self care techniques - is there a trigger? Avoid it and avoid as much as possible the compulsion to itch
- Steroid creams - these reduce the inflammation and are very helpful
- Moisturising creams - these maintain the skin barrier. Use them for a long period of time even when the skin looks completely healthy

Comment: This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)

Comment: I consulted with a doctor and he prescribed me some pills. He also suggested me to put powder over the affected skin before wearing socks....I have also started to the apply the combination of neem oil + castor oil + mustard oil on the affected skin and the pus discharge has stopped for now. Waiting to see improvements